# Disk '______' doesn't contain a valid partition table

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap

Having recently run through [EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap), I now get 3 separate 'Disk doesn't contain a valid partition table' when I run `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--t10194-root doesn't contain a valid partition table  <br/>
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--t10194-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table  <br/>
Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Output of `sudo swapon --all --verbose`:

```
swapon on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--t10194-swap_1  <br/>
swapon: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--t10194-swap_1: read swap header failed: Invalid argument
```

How can I get rid of the 3 separate 'doesn't contain a valid partition table' errors?

Answer (score 2):

/dev/mapper/* are usually LVM2 or DM volumes. They mostly don't and shouldn't contain partition tables - you can safely ignore these warnings.

Your swap partition seems to be /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 which again, is an LVM2 or DM volume.

You can verify swap partitions being used by your system by running `cat /proc/swaps` and if what you expect is there, you can safely ignore those warnings.

PS. what does your /etc/fstab look like?